# CSipsimple-Capture Packet loss with KeepAlive

Tags: android, sip, voip, pjsip, csip-simple

Is it possible to capture % packet loss in csipsimple using keepalive feature in TCP mode? I want to capture packet loss every 2 minutes. is this possible? Any pointer?